# Organization chart component for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, organization, charts

I need a "free" organization chart component for ASP.NET.

Comment: http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-org-chart-in-aspnet.html

Comment: I made this one using Jit js : https://github.com/rlopez0689/OrgChartJit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google has a free one within their charting api's. http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html

Comment: thnx , your replay helped me a lot :)

Comment: hello @Mahmoud! will you plz tell me how to bind the datatable using this API and display Organisation chart in asp.net? waiting for your response...! 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: hello @Brownman98! will you plz tell me how to bind the DataTable in .aspx page using this API and display Organisation chart in asp.net? waiting for your response...! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The control works with a local JS array of objects. What you can do is on the server side get your data then serialize that object into a JSON string. You then store the string in a hidden field. When the page loads you can parse the JSON into an object.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite resources for free web components and examples are:

- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com)
- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com)
- [The ASP.NET Control Gallery](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/)

I found this at the control gallery. Maybe it'll help.

http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3224

Comment: This one might be better suited: http://orgchartwebcontrol.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Robert: It sure looks sharper. Thanks for adding the link.

Answer (score 2):

Chart4.NET is an advanced organization chart component that has a free version.
But logo will be there.

Demo:

- http://organization.unifosys.com/Create_Organization_Chart_From_Database_Sample_WebForm.aspx
- http://unifosys.com/hierarchy-chart/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a HTML5/canvas version of organization chart lib, simple interface + image node support, check it out here: http://orgplot.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Use this http://orgchartwebcontrol.codeplex.com/releases/view/34288 from codeplex